# Cors XmlHttpRequest and Response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

### Description of Task

I'm creating a program with a client/server architecture. The server is a javascript script running in the users's browser, the client is a application running on the user's local machine. The script posts a GET request to a port on 127.0.0.1; 2000 for example. The client reads the message, does some action, and posts a reply back to the server.

### Description of Problem

This type of interaction is considered to be cross-origin resource sharing. I've read the material [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and written my program to respond to the request using with appropriate cors header messages. Unfortunately I seem to be getting the error message:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:2000/?Command=test&Parameters=1234. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

### Full Http Exchange

```
GET /?Command=test&Parameters=1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:2000
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Geco) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/test/main.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Custom-Gnat-Client-v1.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Content-Length: 12
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain


Success
```

### Relevant Code

In main.js:

```
var Is_IE                = window.XDomainRequest ? true : false;
var Cross_Domain_xmlhttp = Create_Cross_Domain_Request();

function Create_Cross_Domain_Request(){
  var request;
  if(Is_IE)
    request = new window.XDomainRequest();
  else{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
  return request;
}

...

var URL = "http://127.0.0.1:2000/"+"?Command="+Command_String+"&Parameters=" +Parameters;
if (Cross_Domain_xmlhttp){
  if(Is_IE){
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.onload=function(){
      console.log(Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.send();
  } else {
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.open('GET', URL, true);
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.readyState==4 && Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.status==200){
        console.log(Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    Cross_Domain_xmlhttp.send();
  }
} else {
  alert("The browser does not support XDomainRequest or XmlHttpRequest");
}
```

The client code isn't relevant currently but I will post if requested.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any `Origin: http://127.0.0.1` in server response since it's a request header.

And why not to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1` instead of `*`?

Comment: Well, removing the Origin didn't help. Also it would be ideal for it to be http://127.0.0.1 as Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but I have * there now because I want it to be as permissive as possible until I get it working. Then I'll narrow it down.

Comment: It didn't work either, I bet it has something to do with the encoding of the response. The client, written in Ada, has default Latin-1 string encoding. After some reading, it seems they expect utf-8 encoding.

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference with encoding if you use only latin characters.

Comment: so I went into the network developer tools in chrome and IE 9 and looked at the header/response stuff. IE 9 received the response, though it couldn't render "Success". Chrome didn't receive any response headers at all... wtf?

Comment: which means it's something to do with xmlhttprequest vs. xdomainrequest